# SVG rendering issues using iPython inline plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

when I use inline plots in iPython (QtConsole), the first plot looks (more or less) fine, but then it gets weirder and weirder. When I plot something several times (so plot, see it displayed, plot again, see output etc.), it looks like it is being overlaid with the skewed previous picture. So after plotting a diagonal line (x=y) 4 times in a row I get something like this [image]

If i right click and export it as svg everything looks good [image]

(Exported PNG picture remains wrecked as the first one). 
I guess the problem is similar to https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1866, but I didn't got the upshot of the discussion (it got too technical and complicated for me to follow).
Is there any solution or work around for this issue?

I'm using

```
python 2.7
matplotlib 1.4.1
IPython 2.1.0
```

Here is a working example:

```
%matplotlib inline
% config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=range(10)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a,a)
ax.axis('off')
```

if you remove `plt.axis('off')` line, weird things happen only outside of the axis box.

P.S. Originally I encountered this problem in connection with drawing graphs with `networkx`. If I use `draw` from `networkx` this problem does not occur. If I use `draw_networkx`, same as described above happens. That might point to the core of the problem... I'm trying to figure out what line of code makes one work better than the other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering around with the `draw` and `draw_networkx` functions from `networkx` module, I found the workaround which makes the difference between `draw` and `draw_networkx` in this case.
Adding `fig.set_facecolor('w')` overlays whatever is in the background, so the new plots are started with a white sheet (but not a blank one, I guess).
So new working example is:

```
%matplotlib inline
% config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=range(10)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
fig.set_facecolor('w')
ax.plot(a,a)
ax.axis('off')
```